# can't display files details that are saved in phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

I'm building a project with angular and php, I have a "file" table that I can upload files using only php. now I'm trying to retrieve all files details in my database. my error in the console is:

```
 angular.js:13550 SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
```

can someone please check my code?

Php for displaying:

```
    <?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
  $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','hamatkin');

  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_client = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_connection = utf8");
  mysqli_query($connection,"SET character_set_results = utf8");

  if(!$connection){
    die("couldnt connect".mysqli_error);
  }
  $query = "SELECT * FROM `file` ";
  $queryResult = $connection->query($query);

  $queryResult2 = array();
  if($queryResult === FALSE) { die($connection->error); }
  if( $queryResult->num_rows>0){
    while($row = $queryResult->fetch_assoc()){
      $queryResult2[] = $row;
    }
  }
  $queryResult3 = json_encode($queryResult2);
   echo json_encode($queryResult3);
?>
```

Controller:

```
"use strict";

angular.module('dataSystem').controller('allPriceOffersCtrl', function($scope,$route,$location,$http) {
  $http({method:'GET', url:'api/customers-tab/get-all-priceOffers.php/'})
      .then(function(response) {
        var arr = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(response.data));
        $scope.files = arr;
      })

      // This will log you the error code and trace, if there is an error.

      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('err', err)
      });

});
```

Html:

```
    <div class="table-responsive">
  <table  class="customer-list table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="Column-Header">מספר</th>
        <th class="Column-Header">משו</th>
        <th class="Column-Header">שם מלא</th>
        <th class="Column-Header">ת.ז./עוסק מורשה</th>
        <th class="Column-Header">עיר</th>
        <th class="Column-Header">כתובת</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in files">
        <!-- <td>{{$index + 1}}</td> -->
        <td>{{ x.id}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.name}}</td>
        <td>{{ x.mime}}</td>
        <td> {{ x.size}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.data}} </td>
        <td> {{ x.created}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @MarkusLaire what is missing in "if"? I didn't understand. what are you suggesting to do with  $queryResult2?

Comment: I believe you should initialize `$queryResult2=array();`  before you use it. probably won't fix your error, but should be done nevertheless

Comment: Sorry misread that `if` because of no spaces.

Comment: Why do you effective use `echo json_encode(json_encode($queryResult2));` instead of just single json_encode?

Comment: @Jakumi the code in the controller should work because I can display other tables in my database. I don't know why in this I have the error I wrote

Comment: Which browser are you using? If you're using Google Chrome, near the error you posted you can click on it and see what's the JSON repsonse. Could be a PHP Error there and you'll get more info about the problem.

Comment: @Kamae I am using Google Chrome, how to check Json response?

Comment: Debug your code. I'm absolutely certain that your php-script produces an error message (format: `<strong>Error/Warning/whatever ...`) which of course is no JSON, which leads to the parsing error. So ... just use your browser to access the php-page and read that error message there

Comment: @Kamae Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\wamp64\www\hamatkin\api\customers-tab\get-all-priceOffers.php on line <i>14</i></th></tr>
u ment this

Comment: @Jakumi can u please check the error I wrote now to Kamae?

Comment: Yes, so there is the problem, in get-all-priceOffers.php line 14. Getting a property of a non-object is usually when the SQL fails or doesn't return any row and you try to access to one property. Could you edit your answer and add this file? (at least the block of lines with regard to the line 14)

Comment: You should first check if your `$queryResult` isn't `false` (`===` or `!==`). and if it is `false` you should get the error message. use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to get the error

Comment: @Kamae I didn't understand what to edit and what file to add?

Comment: @jakumi can you write how to check? i'm new with php

Comment: Sorry I meant the code of that file, but I noticed is the first code you already added. Try the @Jakumi's answer ;)

Comment: SO is not for debugging help, per se, but hey. after your ->query(); you write `if($queryResult === FALSE) { die($connection->error); }` which should output the error to the php page (so browse it with your browser again)

Comment: @Jakumi thanks for all the advices! now it says "response = Object {data: "Unknown column 'date' in 'order clause'", status: 200, config: Object," what does that mean please?

Comment: it means that the table you are querying has no column `date`, but you want to order the rows by the column `date`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typical case of debug-unfriendly code.

First, you have to check if your `$connection->query` possibly returned an error, meaning, the return value is not a resultset but `false`. So

```
if($queryResult === false) {
    die($connection->error);
}
```

Even then you should have a "sane" result, meaning, you expect an array of arrays, so `$queryResult2` at least should be initialized as an array:

```
$queryResult2 = array(); // before the while loop.
```

Also: You absolutely don't need to check the `num_rows`, just do the while loop, because it will just not do anything wrong if there are no rows. `fetch` is that smart!

As it turns out, the column `date` that is being ordered by, didn't exist.

After debugging for an ridiculously long time, we found out, that there's probably binary data stored in the database and the `json_encode()` returned false due to a "malformed utf8 character". The angularjs part had to be adapted to not decode / parse json too often. I was under the assumption, that no binary data was stored in the database. Let this be a warning, don't have any assumptions when debugging. Always check for error return values.

Debug-friendly code helps. Please, world, write debug-friendly code, because it isn't much of a hassle to do and debugging becomes as easy as putting the error message into some search engine and not let stackoverflow debug your code in the comments of your question.

Comment: in my database "file" table this are my columns: 
id/
name/
mime/
size/
data/
created - this is where it sets the data

Comment: and you try to order by `date` where it maybe ... `created`?

Comment: I didn't see that you awesome! I will change now and try again

Comment: ok now I have no errors but still not displaying, and when I debug in "sources" it says :response = Object {data: "false", status: 200, config: Object, statusText: "OK"} why data gets false?

Comment: please append your current code to your question. Also: are there any files in your table? ^

Comment: I will edit now, and yes I have files in my database

Comment: can you please check?

Comment: what is the output if you go the php page directly? because that response in angular is not consistent with what you said and the code you provided.

Comment: what do you mean "go to php page directly"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118913/discussion-between-jakumi-and-tanyaa).